# How to run function without openning sqlite connection everytime

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I have this code below. Every time the function runs it wont add the data into the database because I didn't connect to the sqlite database inside the function. How can I run this function without having to connect and disconnect from the database every time the function runs. Is this even possible?

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('hist_data.db')
c = conn.cursor()


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code " + str(rc))
    client.subscribe("MY TOPIC 1")
    client.subscribe('MY TOPIC 2')




def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
print("this is the msg payload: " + str(msg.payload))
if str(msg.topic) == "MY TOPIC 1":
    print('starts loop')
    msg = msg.payload
    msg = msg.decode('utf-8')
    print("decoded message: " + msg)
    msg = str(msg)
    print("message as string: "+ msg)
    msg = msg.rstrip()
    print('msg stripped: '+msg)
    print(type(msg))
    msg = msg.split(" ")
    ph = float(msg[0])
    print(f'ph: {ph}')
    water_level = int(msg[1])
    print(f'water_level: {water_level}')
    humidity = float(msg[2])
    print(f'humidity: {humidity}')
    air_temp = float(msg[3])
    print(f"air_temp: {air_temp}")
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    print(f"timestamp: {timestamp}")
    data = [(ph,air_temp,humidity,water_level,timestamp)]
    print(f'this is the data in list tuple: {data}')
    c.executemany("INSERT INTO sensor_data(ph,air_temp,humidity,water_level,timestamp) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)",data)
    print("it was executed")
    conn.commit()
if str(msg.topic) == "MY TOPIC 2":
    msg = msg.payload
    water_temp = msg.decode('utf-8')
    print(f'decoded msg : {water_temp}')
    water_temp = float(water_temp)
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM sensor_data WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM sensor_data)")
    print('inserted data')
    c.execute("UPDATE sensor_data SET water_temp = (?) WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM sensor_data)",(water_temp,))
    print('updated it')
    # c.execute("insert into sensor_data(water_temp) values(?)",[(ph),])
    conn.commit()
    print('done')
```

Comment: Function accept parameter called `client` and that must be a DB connection handler. Then, you're trying to execure SQL using `c.executemany` but I do not see that `c` is defined somewhere.

Comment: Same for `conn` - it should commit the query but where does it's defined?

Comment: sorry, I only included the function by mistake. I included the rest of the code

Comment: oh, I think i see my problem. Do I have to connect to the database within the function for this to work?

Comment: you should use your connection that you passed to a function (I guess `client` it's actually it)

Comment: def on_message(client, userdata, msg,c,conn):      --something like that?

Comment: No, I mean `client` (I guess) is actually a DB connection object and `c` is looks like a cursore and conn is rather a client. So, `c = client.cursor()` and `client.commit()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I simply added the code below to the "on message" function. I guess I have to connect to the database within functions, when I previously thought if i make the connection outside the script the function will realize the connection.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('hist_data.db')
c = conn.cursor()
```